# Only having STATE NEW in iptables will block ESTABLISHED connections?

Tags: centos, iptables, centos6, vps

My iptables is now like this:

```
Table: filter
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:12001 
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:12001 
3    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW udp dpt:8989 
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:8989 
5    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8888
```

The STATE NEW rule on port 8989 will pass new connections. However, will it block all established connections on port 8989?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's your entire INPUT chain, it's not blocking anything because the INPUT policy is ACCEPT and you have no DROP rule(s).

If you want a functioning firewall, you need to either change the INPUT policy to DROP or add a DROP rule. But yes, if you do that, you'll also need a rule to accept established connections. You can do that like so:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

That accepts all established connections as the first input rule, which is generally a reasonable thing to do.

If you're connecting by ssh, make sure to accept both new and established tcp connections on your ssh port before you add the DROP policy or rule. Otherwise you might lock yourself out.

Comment: Now my firewall is accepting inputs from all ports? or it's only accepting inputs from listed ports? I am new to Linux sorry.

Comment: Do I need to add ACCEPT rules for listening ports?

Comment: Correct. What you posted is accepting everything. Nothing is blocked. You currently have no firewall. To change that, you need to either set the policy to DROP or add at least one DROP rule. Before you do that, make sure you have ACCEPT rules for on ports you need to have open for minimum functionality.